# Generate a Pushdown Automaton that accepts the strings from the language $L=\{a^ib^jc^k, i + k \ne j\}$

Tags: automata

I am trying to generate a Pushdown Automaton that accepts the strings of the language $L=\{a^i b^j c^k, i + k \ne j\}$.

From this I know that the following situations can occur: $i + k < j$ or $i + k > j$ which seems to mean that I will be merging two different automata, but I am not sure how to go about doing so due to the given condition.

How do I go about solving?

Comment: Every time you see a, push a onto the stack. then when you start seeing b's, push off until the stack is empty. then start pushing b's in. then when you see c's, push off b's.